# sql server matching field containing "$$" and "%"

Tags: sql, where-clause, collate

One of my column in sql table contain values like

```
$$ADC.ES%32,A
```

How can I match this in my select where clause?

```
Select .... From .... Where ColumnName = '$$ADC.ES%32,A'
```

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you execute that query? i think it seems fine since you are not searching for pattern.

Comment: it should find it, see this, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae7a5/1

Comment: unless the actual value in the table is a UNICODE or binary string that is when displayed in the result window gets converted to  $$ADC.ES%32,A. Also, %32 part of the result suggests that you use some sort of HTML query analyser. %32 most likely is a space. Try  Where ColumnName = '$$ADC.ES ,A' and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

it should find with your query any way try this

select * from table where name like '$$ADC.ES%32,A'